# ruby/rails: what is the right way to refer to some_user.user_profile.name if user might not have a user_profile yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the correct way to refer to current_user.user_profile.name when there may or may not be a user_profile record for a particular user?

I have two tables, User (:email) and UserProfile (:name, :company).

User `has_one` user_profile, and UserProfile `belongs_to` User

A profile may or may not not exist. (It's optional for users)

In lot of my code and views I want to display the user's name and company, for example `current_user.user_profile.name`

Of course, if the user has not created their profile yet, current_user.user_profile is nil, so referencing current_user.user_profile.name throws an error.

I know how to do it the wrong way (check for nil before referencing the .name field EVERY time I need the name).

The best I can think of is create a User method called `name` that does the nil checking so current_user.name returns the name (or "" if there is no profile). But that feels wrong, too, since I have to write a method for every single field I add to user_profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this that should work with all attributes of the `UserProfile`:

```
# User.rb
def try_this(attribute)
  self.user_profile ? self.user_profile.send(attribute) : "Not Available"
end
```

Then you'd just call

```
current_user.try_this(:name)
```

**Edit**

Dylan's `try` method also works:

```
def try_this(attribute)
  self.user_profile.try(attribute) || "Not Available"
end
```

Comment: great solution because it also addresses the issue of not having to re-write the same thing for N different fields in user_profile! I'll implement it like this, with a name along the lines of try_profile() so I can also add try_foo() and try_bar() for other models.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the Law of Demeter answers, but Rails has a convenient way for your User class to delegate :name and other methods to its user_profile:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user_profile

    delegate :name, :email, :phone, :height, :etc,
        to: :user_profile, allow_nil: true, prefix: :profile

end
```

Now these:

```
user.profile_name
user.profile_email
user.profile_phone
```

will return nil if `user.user_profile` is nil, and otherwise return `user.user_profile.name`, `user.user_profile.email`, and `user.user_profile.phone`, respectively. But they hide that fact from callers, who only interact with User. You could leave off the prefix option if you'd rather have this:

```
user.name
user.email
user.phone
```

In general I'd shy away from strategies that involve exceptions or `rescue`, unless a nil user_profile is truly something that should not happen. And I'd hate to use andand or try because they push the responsibility of managing the user_profile to callers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `try`:

```
current_user.user_profile.try(:name) || "Not Available"
```

When you use `rescue`, there's a risk that you may be rescuing from a different type of error than `NoMethodError` as a result of `user_profile` being `nil`.

Comment: thanks, though it seems less than ideal to have to use that sequence every single place I refer to every single field in current_user.user_profile

Answer (score 1):

```
current_user.andand.user_profile.name || "Not Available"
```

The ["andand" gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) implements null-safe chaining.

As you suggest, creating a `User.name` method may be preferable (and [Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) would be proud).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The *best* way, according to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), is to add a method on User with this logic. Whatever needs the user's name shouldn't need to know about user_profile.

> Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.

So...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   def user_name
      user_profile ? user_profile.name : ""
   end

[...]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`current_user.user_profile.name rescue "Not Available"`